# Help understanding the data in a validator deposit file

Tags: staking

I want to understand how the data in a validator deposit file is generated. Below is an example.

```
[{
    "pubkey": "a2610776da5aba91a5603a4f3ed17c850246bf13955dc860e1e58e1a2e3a8de95553dd70829e5f96c8b2696703d43356",
    "withdrawal_credentials": "00bad71f5cabb6a5d11ad43e59964a3483284ba2d5a2bdfe14a75a0e314df714",
    "amount": 32000000000,
    "signature": "8754aac097036e3b90c95197737a04050862ac7073baececde4102e902a980caf78ac0ac6a74c5a76e776bc9a577f8d716672459dbd022e948125e17443a8cec4ad6b2f07b7082a488eb86f5cbf3bf388443166bc1b10be5d6343c9e5c3ad284",
    "deposit_message_root": "612b5ff9748f9552169f2514fd4aa8f1eb4c4b5f8e13564d1472651669af86c8",
    "deposit_data_root": "65f172c0819272406bac02915916a36cc0d5ab4411d86a11d4bc6be38e96529f",
    "fork_version": "00000000",
    "network_name": "mainnet",
    "deposit_cli_version": "2.3.0"
}]
```

Specifically I'm wondering about `deposit_message_root`, `deposit_data_root`, and what data the signature is signing.

I've tried to look through `staking-deposit-cli` of course, and got as far as finding out it had something to do with `ssz` and a function called `hash_tree_root`. What I have found so far:

1. It appears like `deposit_message_root` is a serialized hash of `DepositMessage`, a structure containing 3 things: (a) the `pubkey`, or `a2610776da5aba91a5603a4f3ed17c850246bf13955dc860e1e58e1a2e3a8de95553dd70829e5f96c8b2696703d43356`, (b) the `withdrawal_credentials`, or `00bad71f5cabb6a5d11ad43e59964a3483284ba2d5a2bdfe14a75a0e314df714`, and (c) `amount` at `32000000000`. Calling `hash_tree_root` on the above `DepositMessage` object results in `612b5ff9748f9552169f2514fd4aa8f1eb4c4b5f8e13564d1472651669af86c8`.
2. It appears like the BLS signature is being done on a serialized hash of a `SigningData` structure, containing 2 things: (a) the `deposit_message_root`, or `612b5ff9748f9552169f2514fd4aa8f1eb4c4b5f8e13564d1472651669af86c8`, and (b) what appeared to be a constant called the "deposit domain" I wasn't able to find. I assume that calling `hash_tree_root` on this `SigningData` object would also get you a 64 character hex string that is meant to be signed with the private BLS key corresponding to `pubkey`.
3. It appears like `deposit_data_root` is a serialized hash of `DepositData`, a structure containing 4 things total: the 3 same things from `DepositMessage` *and* the `signature`, or `8754aac097036e3b90c95197737a04050862ac7073baececde4102e902a980caf78ac0ac6a74c5a76e776bc9a577f8d716672459dbd022e948125e17443a8cec4ad6b2f07b7082a488eb86f5cbf3bf388443166bc1b10be5d6343c9e5c3ad284`. Calling `hash_tree_root` on the above `DepositData` object results in `65f172c081927240bac02915916a36cc0d5ab4411d86a11d4bc6be38e96529f`.

I'm hoping you can confirm whether I'm right so far or not in each of these 3 cases, and help figuring out what the constant from #2 is as well as how to calculate these hashes myself in the future.

Answer (score 0):

both are [ssz](https://ethereum.org/es/developers/docs/data-structures-and-encoding/ssz/) objects.
In the [Beacon Deposit Contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000219ab540356cBB839Cbe05303d7705Fa#code), you can see how deposit_data_root is reconstructed in the deposit() funciton.

```
// Compute deposit data root (`DepositData` hash tree root)
        bytes32 pubkey_root = sha256(abi.encodePacked(pubkey, bytes16(0)));
        bytes32 signature_root = sha256(abi.encodePacked(
            sha256(abi.encodePacked(signature[:64])),
            sha256(abi.encodePacked(signature[64:], bytes32(0)))
        ));
        bytes32 node = sha256(abi.encodePacked(
            sha256(abi.encodePacked(pubkey_root, withdrawal_credentials)),
            sha256(abi.encodePacked(amount, bytes24(0), signature_root))
        ));

        // Verify computed and expected deposit data roots match
        require(node == deposit_data_root, "DepositContract: reconstructed DepositData does not match supplied deposit_data_root");
```

You can also use lodestar packages to compute it.